# In CTE Recursive Query,Iam not getting rows that have parentid as NULL

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_SelectProduct_Names
@Parent_Id int=NULL
AS

WITH cteQuery(Product_ID,Product_Name,Parent_Id)
AS
(
    SELECT Product_Id,Product_Name,Parent_Id 
    FROM tbl_Product_Master
    WHERE Parent_Id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.Product_ID,p.Product_Name,p.Parent_Id 
    FROM tbl_Product_Master p
         JOIN cteQuery ON cteQuery.Product_ID=p.Parent_Id
)
```

PROBLEM is Iam not getting rows that have parentid as NULL

Below are the two rows.

```
Product_Id Product_Code Product_Name Store_Name Parent_Id Brand_Name Created_Date IsEnabled
1          NULL         ABC          jsj        NULL      DD         2007-02-15   1
11         567          zzz          ER         1         WWW        2017-02-15   1
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @McNets But other fields are not null, so it would appear...

Comment: Show the complete query.

Comment: @JohnHC This would simply return all products then.

Comment: is this a recursive query on a parent-child related rows?

Comment: it should work: http://rextester.com/LMA97411  check id - parent_id values

Comment: the two rows are the result you get? What is your initial data of table tbl_Product_Master?

Comment: You are getting rows with a perent_id null. What is your problem ?